# Optimal taxation and substitute commodities

Tags: macroeconomics, taxation, optimal-taxation

Reading Ramsey's paper: a contribution to the theory of taxation. It says that when we are dealing with rival goods we look if the tax that is going to be applied leave unchanged the proportions in wich these goods are consumed. Alike Ramsey presents that in order to avoid evasion by consume another good that it's no taxed. The tax must be applied in the commoditie that is least elastic. Taking into account the above, What happened when we are dealing with substitue commodites? Does the supposed that the consume of a good depends only of its price is still standing?

Comment: Hi. Could you fix this sentence: "Does the supposed that the consume of a good depends only of its price is still standing?" It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sure, sorry. What i meant to ask was, if we are still assuming that the demand of a good depends only of ite price, even when is a substitute good